# SimpleDateFormat Ignore Characters

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am using a `SimpleDateFormat` and I am getting results from two different sources. One source uses the format `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`, while the other uses `"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"`. I am not interested in obtaining the time zone ('Z' value) from the second format, is there a way I can obtain these times without using different format strings? Something that will ignore the middle character as well as the characters after `'ss'`.

Comment: Just mutate the string to truncate it after the seconds, and normalize the part between the date and time?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want that `Z`? It marks that the time is relative to UTC. Without it the date will be interpreted as if it's in your current time zone, despite the source providing it based on UTC. Are you sure that this won't cause you to record wrong times?

Comment: @JonSkeet I know I could do that, but I am trying to simplify my code using GSON. So getting the string first, mutating it, and putting it back into the JSON string would be pretty counter-intuitive. I may just have to use two separate GSON objects, but I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: @RealSkepitc I know that all of the dates will be in the same time zone, so  it's not important. If there is a way I can do both with one string, as well as keep the time zone, I would be fine with that also.

Comment: Well, someone has to understand both format. Isn't it? Are you asking for some existing library or function which understands both formats? Have you checked http://www.date4j.net/javadoc/index.html ?

Answer (score 6):

The cleanest and clearest solution is if you can separate the strings from the two sources and use an appropriate formatter for each.

Another approach that you might consider is “taking a taste” to determine which format you’ve got and pick the formatter based on that. For example `if (result.contains("T") && results.endsWith("Z"))`.

Since you asked about avoiding different format strings, that is possible too:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd[ ]['T']HH:mm:ss[X]");

    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse("2015-11-06 21:23:18", formatter));
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse("2018-08-25T08:18:49Z", formatter));
```

Output from this snippet is:

> ```
> 2015-11-06T21:23:18
> 2018-08-25T08:18:49
> ```

I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is long outdated and notoriously troublesome. Instead I recommend you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It’s so much nicer to work with.

The square brackets denote optional parts of the format. The format will accept also a string that has both a space and a `T` in the middle, and one that hasn’t got any of them. For most purposes I suggest that we can live with that. Edit: You cannot play a similar trick with `SimpleDateFormat`, it does not accept square brackets or any other syntax for optional parts.

I am not happy about ignoring the offset in the second string and doing that only because you said you wanted to. I’d clearly prefer the following just slightly longer solution:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd[ ]['T']HH:mm:ss[X]")
            .withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);

    System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse("2015-11-06 21:23:18", formatter));
    System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-08-25T08:18:49Z", formatter));
```

Output is the same, only now with offset:

> ```
> 2015-11-06T21:23:18Z
> 2018-08-25T08:18:49Z
> ```

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old but for the date with the T in the middle and the time zone at the end "2018-08-24T08:02:05-04:00" use the following in your simpledateformat: "yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ssX"

Comment: The issue is that when parsing the date string `SimpleDateFormat` expects any uninterpreted characters – characters surrounded by single quotes (eg. `'T'`) or characters not within `[a-z][A-Z]` – to be in the parsed string. If the uninterpreted characters are not there it will throw an error. If I have two formats, one with an uninterpreted character and one without, I haven't found a way to create a single format that will accept both.